How do I deal with default values in extern functions?
The basic function:
void foo(int bar=99){
};

And in the #include'd routine:
extern void foo(int);
foo();

This doesn't compile as it says 1 argument is required for foo().  If I make it:
extern void foo(int=99);
foo();

This also doesn't compile, saying the default value was previously specified.  Ideally I'd want one default in the main routine, and a different default in the #include'd routine - is that possible?
I've also tried:
extern void foo(int bar=99);


default value for function argument should be specified only in a header file with declaration of function.

Related reading: Extern functions in C vs C++. In short, there's no reason to use extern for functions.

It should, in fact, be specified by every declaration of the function (the “prototype”), and should be the same each time. (Ideally there should only be a single one, in the #include file). The definition of the function should not (unless it is also the declaration).

Thanks for responses; yes I'm surprised!  Putting the default value in the function declaration in the header (and not in the specification of the function itself) works, but in the #include'd routine with extern void foo(int), it still says that foo() isn't found (i.e. it doesn't know about the default). A workaround is to define void foo(){foo(99);} in the #includ'd routine.

You gonna be surprised...
If I understood correctly, you want to have a one file with function foo, e.g. myfunc.cpp:
#include <iostream>

void foo(int bar) {
    printf("Hello world %i !", bar);
};

and other e.g. externexample.cpp that uses function foo with default argument:
void foo(int foo = 99);

int main()
{
    foo();
}

So you have to understand that default values are not part of object file (maybe we should say that they are not part of ABI - Application Binary Interface), similarly parameter names are not either (I changed int bar to int foo).
Default values are set by the compiler in the calling code, the called function has no idea that such a value has been used. In sufficiently messy code, there may even be different default values for different files.
So it is important to use common header .h files to standardise the function call in all places. And such a .h file should keep a declaration with default value.


Ideally I'd want one default in the main routine, and different default in the #included routine - is that possible?

You cannot have that behavior from default argument.
From Default arguments

If an inline function is declared in different translation units, the accumulated sets of default arguments must be the same at the end of each translation unit.

and since C++20:

If a non-inline function is declared in the same namespace scope in different translation units, the corresponding default arguments must be the same if present (but some default arguments can be absent in some TU).

